# What is the best way to calculate / store a line_item total in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have `line_items` with `unit_price` and `quantity` attributes (amongst others).

What is the best way to model this in Ruby on Rails?

Right now, lots of functions in my `LineItem` model follow this pattern:

```
def total_price
  unit_price * quantity
end
```

This works, but I would like to know: Is this approach useful or will it bring my app to its knees when a million users are using it at the same time?

An alternative would be to store the `total_price` as a database field that gets updated with something like this after each save: `after_save :update_total`. I am not a big fan of redundant database columns though. I would like to keep them to a minimum.

What is the *professional* way of doing this?

Comment: how would a single message containing a single multiplication bring an application to its knees? there's no 1 correct answer to this question.

Comment: OK, basically I am just wondering if it's better to calculate a value or store it in the database. It is probably faster to read a value from the database than calculating it on each request?

Comment: think about the complications you might introduce if you set the total in a field in the table.
what if unit_price change in case you have price discount, or quantity changes, you'll then need to update the total in each case.

Comment: Faster to read the database than calculate a value? I doubt it, unless you are doing some very heavy calculations. But, that's really easy for you to figure out by using Ruby's Benchmark class and writing a simple test.

Comment: @vitaLee so how would you calculate the sum of total_price of all line_items sold in 2012 in Rails ( when the calculation of total_price gets a little bit complicated with discounts, surcharges, taxes ..) ??

Comment: @Klaus - that task would be difficult and unpleasent enough to convince Tintin81, that the right thing is to add the field to the table. (doh)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the general problem of computed value vs storage. I'm not sure there is a single answer for all cases, but here are some elements to take into account :

- Is the computation **costly** ? If yes, better to **store**
- Are the **variable like unit_price changing** ? If yes, better to **compute**, because if you store, you'll have to recompute all total_price when unit_price changes
- Will you **query on the computed value** ? If yes, better to **store** and to use the database capabilities (for example, if you want all product with a total price bigger than 500).
- Note that in this (simple) case, the database can be asked to do also the computation (WHERE UNIT_PRICE * QUANTITY > 500), but some kind of computation may not be possible or convenient to express in SQL.

For all the "performance" aspects, the only correct answer is : measure. You cannot tell that beforehand. That means that initially, pick the easiest way (I would compute), profile, then see if there is a reason to switch. Rails and Ruby are full of profiling tools (you can starts with Rails [performance testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html)).